# Changes to iteration variable not reflected in original list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to implement a HTML escape function

This is my code:

```
def escape_html(s):
    for x in s:
        if x == '>':
            x = "&gt"
        elif x == '<':
            x = "&lt"
        elif x == ' " ':
            x = "&quot"
    return s

s = "dasdasdas > < "
print escape_html(s)
```

My output is exactly the same as my input. Why are the characters not replaced?

Expected output:

```
dasdasdas &gt &lt
```

Actual output:

```
dasdasdas > <
```

Comment: Why don't you use existing functionality like cgi.escape()?

Comment: There are a couple of other issues with your example, even if the string replacement was correct: the escape sequence should be terminated with a semicolon `;`, and you shouldn't have spaces around the double-quote `' " '` or it won't work.

Comment: aren't strings immutable in python? you're trying to mutate a string and reassigning the variable  `x` inswtead

Comment: I know this is about Python 2.7, but it's noteworthy that in Python 3.2 and up there's also html.escape from the [html module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/html.html) which also features a HTML-specific parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop iterates through the iterable given and sets the variable before the `in` each time through the loop. It's a variable like any other. If you tried this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
x = my_list[1]
x = 5
```

Then you'd not have `my_list` equal `[1, 5, 3]` at the end; no, rather than changing where you got `x` from, you just re-bound `x`. You're having the same issue with your `x`. You'll need to explicitly place it back into `s` somehow.

Anyway, **if you want to practically escape HTML, just use [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape).**

Answer (score 0):

Along with what @icktoofay said, `x` will take on the value of every character in `s`. How do you expect a character to equal `' " '`? You should probably work with indexes instead. Here is a modified version of your function that does what you desire (it is still very incomplete however and `cgi.escape` would be the best way):

```
>>> def escape_html(s):
        x = ''
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] == '>':
                x += "&gt"
            elif s[i] == '<':
                x += "&lt"
            elif s[i:i + 3] == ' " ':
                x += "&quot"
            else:
                x += s[i]
        return x


>>> print escape_html("dasdasdas > < ")
dasdasdas &gt &lt
```